# My Haskell code has type annotation errors and can't figure out what those are

Tags: haskell

Here is the code I wrote:

```
multiApp :: (a -> a) -> [a -> a] -> a -> [a]
multiApp f [] x = []
multiApp f gs x = f $ multiAppi gs x

multiAppi :: [a -> a] -> a -> [a]
multiAppi [] x = []
multiAppi gs x = ((head gs) x) : multiAppi (tail gs) x
```

I'm trying to use list of functions to a value and then use function f to that list.

Examples:

```
multiApp id [] 7  ==> []

multiApp id [id, reverse, tail] "This is a test" ==> ["This is a test","tset a si sihT","his is a test"]

multiApp id  [(1+), (^3), (+2)] 1  ==>  [2,1,3]

multiApp sum [(1+), (^3), (+2)] 1  ==>  6

multiApp reverse [tail, take 2, reverse] "foo" ==> ["oof","fo","oo"]

multiApp concat [take 3, reverse] "race" ==> "racecar"
```

Here is answer:

```
Set3a.hs:269:34: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `multiAppi (tail gs) x'
      In the expression: ((head gs) x) : multiAppi (tail gs) x
      In an equation for `multiAppi':
          multiAppi gs x = ((head gs) x) : multiAppi (tail gs) x
    * Relevant bindings include
        x :: a (bound at Set3a.hs:269:14)
        gs :: [a -> a] (bound at Set3a.hs:269:11)
        multiAppi :: [a -> a] -> a -> a (bound at Set3a.hs:268:1)
    |
269 | multiAppi gs x = ((head gs) x) : multiAppi (tail gs) x
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What infinite type? What???

Edit:
Now code reads like this:

```
multiApp :: ([a] -> b) -> [a -> a] -> a -> b
multiApp f gs x = f $ multiAppi gs x

multiAppi :: [a -> a] -> a -> [a]
multiAppi [] x = []
multiAppi (g:gs) x = g x : multiAppi gs x
```

And errors for sum function is like:

set3atest.hs:232:42: error:
* Couldn't match type `Int' with` [Int]'
Expected type: Int -> Int
Actual type: [Int] -> Int
* In the expression: head
In the second argument of `multiApp', namely` [head, last]'
In the first argument of `(?==)', namely` multiApp (sum :: [Int] -> Int) [head, last] [1 :: Int, 2, 3, 4]'
|
232 |              multiApp (sum::[Int]->Int) [head, last] [1::Int,2,3,4] ?== 5
|                                          ^^^^

And this stackoverflow demands less code and more comments. I don't know how to more comment this...

Comment: I can not reproduce this error, there is a problem with your `multiApp`, but not `multiAppi`. Based on the error message, you used `[a -> a] -> a -> a` instead of `[a -> a] -> a -> [a]`.

Comment: `multiApp f gs x = f $ multiAppi gs x` seems strange. You're applying `f` to `[a]`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: based on the examples, `f` should be of type `[a] -> b`, and the `multiApp` should be `([a] -> b) -> [a -> a] -> a -> b`, it is thus some variant of a "map reduce".

Comment: "infinite type" means that you code only makes sense for a type `a` which is equal to `[a]` -- that would mean `a = [a] = [[a]] = [[[a]]] = ...`, i.e. `a` should be the type of lists-of-lists-of-lists-of... infinitely many times. This error can be triggered by, e.g., the expression `x == x:y`: here `==` requires that `x` and `x:y` have the same type, but if we have `x :: a` then `(x:y) :: [a]` hence we also have `x :: [a]`, forcing `a = [a]` and triggering the infinite type error.

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce this error, there is a problem with your `multiApp`, but not `multiAppi`. Based on the error message, you used `[a -> a] -> a -> a` instead of `[a -> a] -> a -> [a]`. You thus should rewrite the signature such that the output is a *list* of `a`s, and reload the file.

Another problem is that for `multiApp` your first function should take a *list* of items `[a]` and convert it to an item `b`, so the signature should be:

```
multiApp :: ([a] -> b) -> [a -> a] -> a -> b
multiApp f gs x = f (multiAppi gs x)
```

your `multiAppi` can be rewritten by making use of a pattern:

```
multiAppi :: [a -> a] -> a -> [a]
multiAppi [] x = []
multiAppi (g:gs) x = g x : multiAppi gs x
```

or simpler with a `map`:

```
multiAppi :: [a -> a] -> a -> [a]
multiAppi gs x = map ($ x) gs
```

Comment: It should work with sum also... It returns non-list.

Comment: @JuhaR: if you alter the signature like is written for the `multiApp`, it will also work with `sum`, `concat`, etc.